Passing additional kwargs to text() from annotate()
I am trying to wrap annotations in my plot, as some are too long.
The annotations were made using the annotate():
matplotlib.pyplot.annotate(text, xy, xytext=None, xycoords='data', textcoords=None, arrowprops=None, annotation_clip=None, **kwargs)

The documentation reads :
 **kwargs
 Additional kwargs are passed to Text.

Does this mean I should be able to pass wrap=True (which is a text() argument to annotate()? How would one do it? (I am totally new to kwargs, never used them)
Documentation

yes, all valid keyword argument or kwargs for Text are listed HERE

Great! So how does one do that? I tried adding wrap =True at the end of my parameters but it doesn't work

In my test, the text wraps at the boundary of the Axes, maybe your text, while long, doesn't reach the right border?  and no, I don't know how to set the width of the text


It seems that wrap=1 works, but the text is wrapped at the right  border of the figure — using directly a Text artist is slightly different, as the text is truncated at the axes border.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text

text = '''The Olmec colossal heads are at least 17 monumental stone representations of human heads sculpted from large basalt boulders. The heads date from at least before 900 BC and are a distinctive feature of the Olmec civilization of ancient Mesoamerica. All portray mature men with fleshy cheeks, flat noses and slightly crossed eyes; their physical characteristics correspond to a type that is still common among the inhabitants of Tabasco and Veracruz. The boulders were brought from the Sierra de los Tuxtlas, a mountain range in Veracruz.'''
fig, ax = plt.subplots(edgecolor='k', linewidth=3)

ax.add_artist(Text(0.0, 0.85, text, wrap=1, fontsize='x-small'))
ax.add_artist(Text(0.4, 0.55, text, wrap=1, fontsize='x-small'))

ax.annotate(text, (0.0,0.35), wrap=1, fontsize='x-small')
ax.annotate(text, (0.4,0.05), wrap=1, fontsize='x-small')
plt.show()

